# Best way to parse a string into Dictionary of terms

Tags: c#, .net, regex, optimization, refactoring

Input - string: `"TAG1xxxTAG2yyyTAG3zzzTAG1tttTAG1bbb"`

Expected result: pairs `TAG1 = {xxx,,ttt,bbb}, TAG2 = {yyy}, TAG3 = {zzz}.`

I did it using regexps, but I'm really confused by using Regex.Replace and not using return value. I want to improve this code, so how can it be realized?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TermsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] tags = { "TAG1", "TAG2", "TAG3", "TAG4", "TAG5", "TAG6", "TAG7", "TAG8" };
            string file = "TAG2jjfjfjndbfdjTAG1qqqqqqqTAG3uytygh fhdjdfTAG5hgjdhfghTAG6trgfmxc hdfhdTAG2jfksksdhjskTAG3kdjbjvbsjTAG2jskjdjdvjvbxjkvbjdTAG2jkxcndjcjbkjn";

            string tag = "(" + string.Join("|", tags) + ")";

            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(tags.Length);
            Regex.Replace(file, string.Format(@"({0})(.+?)(?={0}|$)", tag), match =>
                                                                            {
                                                                                string key = match.Groups[1].Value, value = match.Groups[3].Value;
                                                                                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                                                                                    dictionary[key].Add(value);
                                                                                else
                                                                                    dictionary[key] = new List<string> {value};
                                                                                return "";
                                                                            });
            foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            {
                Console.Write(pair.Key + " =\t");
                foreach (var entry in pair.Value)
                {
                    Console.Write(entry + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string input = "TAG1xxxTAG2yyyTAG3zzzTAG1tttTAG1bbb";
var lookup = Regex.Matches(input, @"(TAG\d)(.+?)(?=TAG|$)")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .ToLookup(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);

foreach (var kv in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + " => " + String.Join(", ", kv));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
TAG1 => xxx, ttt, bbb
TAG2 => yyy
TAG3 => zzz
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks much better!

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect job for the .NET CaptureCollection object—a unique .NET feature that lets you reuse the same capture group multiple times.

Use this regex and use `Matches` to create a MatchCollection:

```
(?:TAG1(.*?(?=TAG|$)))?(?:TAG2(.*?(?=TAG|$)))?(?:TAG3(.*?(?=TAG|$)))?
```

Then inspect the captures:

- `Groups[1].Captures` will contain all the TAG1
- `Groups[2].Captures` will contain all the TAG2
- `Groups[3].Captures` will contain all the TAG3

From there it's a short step to your final data structure.

To reduce the potential for backtracking, you can make the tokens atomic:

```
(?>(?:TAG1(.*?(?=TAG|$)))?)(?>(?:TAG2(.*?(?=TAG|$)))?)(?>(?:TAG3(.*?(?=TAG|$)))?)
```

For details about how this works, see [Capture Groups that can be Quantified](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-csharp.html#quantgroups).

Comment: It seems to be very slow for, for ex, 100 tags. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Okay, let's reduce the potential for backtracking by making the groups atomic: `(?>(?:TAG1(.*?(?=TAG|$)))?)(?>(?:TAG2(.*?(?=TAG|$)))?)(?>(?:TAG3(.*?(?=TAG|$)))?)`

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do is simply grouping of the values of the same tag, so it should be easier to use `GroupBy` method:

```
string input = "TAG1xxxTAG2yyyTAG3zzzTAG1tttTAG1bbb";
var list = Regex.Matches(input, @"(TAG\d+)(.+?)(?=TAG\d+|$)")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .GroupBy(m => m.Groups[1].Value,
                         (key, values) => string.Format("{0} = {{{1}}}", 
                                             key, 
                                             string.Join(", ", 
                                                values.Select(v => v.Groups[2]))));
var output = string.Join(", ", list);
```

This produces as a `output` string `"TAG1 = {xxx, ttt, bbb}, TAG2 = {yyy}, TAG3 = {zzz}"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm aware of all your assumptions and conventions in this problem; but this gave me similar result:

```
var tagColl = string.Join("|", tags);
var tagGroup = string.Format("(?<tag>{0})(?<val>[a-z]*)", tagColl);

var result = from x in Regex.Matches(file, tagGroup).Cast<Match>()
                where x.Success
                let pair = new { fst = x.Groups["tag"].Value, snd = x.Groups["val"].Value }
                group pair by pair.fst into g
                select g;
```

And a simple test would be:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", from g in result
                                        let coll = string.Join(", ", from item in g select item.snd)
                                        select string.Format("{0}: {{{1}}}", g.Key, coll)));
```